# Proof for the fact that $(a,b)$ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

Here is the proof for the fact that $(a,b)$ is not compact.

Proof

$\bigg\{ \left(a+\dfrac{b-a}{2^n}, b \right) \Bigg| n \in \mathbb{N} \bigg\}$ is an open covering of $(a,b)$. Let $U_i:=\left(a+\dfrac{b-a}{2^i}, b\right)$.
Suppose we can cover $(a,b)$ with $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup \cdots \cup U_k $. Then, $a+\dfrac{b-a}{2^{k+1}} \in (a,b)$ and $a+\dfrac{b-a}{2^{k+1}} \notin U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_k.$ This is contradictory.
Thus, $(a,b)$ is not compact.

I understood this proof, but why does this proof use
$\left( a+\dfrac{b-a}{2^n}, b\right)$ ?

I think $\left(a+\dfrac{1}{2^n},b \right)$ also works because $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(a+\dfrac{1}{2^n} \right)=a.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very much a detail, but the interval $(a+\frac{1}{2^n}, b)$ is not always a subset of $(a, b)$. Take $a=0, b=0.1$ then $(a+0.5, b)$ is not a valid subset of $(0, 0.1)$.

Answer (score 4):

What if $b = a + \frac{1}{2^{10000000000}}$?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to use a confusing definition of an interval. The set $(a,b)$ is $$(a,b) = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid a < x < b\}.$$

When $b \geq a$ it is not that this set is somehow `invalid'. It is just empty.

The set $(a+1/n, b)$ is always a subset of $(a, b)$. It's just that it is the empty subset when $a + 1/n \geq b$. The choice of $\frac{b-a}{2^n}$ instead of $\frac 1n$ is not useful, it just makes the typesetting more painful.